# Canvas drawPath with right angle and transparency

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am using Paths, to draw shapes on a canvas. Some of them are completely opaque, some have a very small alpha value, to change the color of the underlying shape just slightly. The problem is that when I have a right angle in one of my shapes with a small alpha value, it seems to make two shapes out of one...

[image]

There are three color values, although its just one shape on a background.

[image]

If I move the lower right point slightly to the right everything is fine.

What is happening here?

This is my code (Anchor == Point):

```
    public void render() {
    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    for(Shape shape : shapes) {
        renderShape(shape);
    }
}

private void renderShape(Shape shape) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(shape.getColorInt());

    Path path = new Path();
    Anchor first = shape.getAnchor(0));
    path.moveTo(widthToScreenCoords(first.getX()), heightToScreenCoords(first.getY()));

    for(int i = 1; i < shape.getAnchorCount(); i++) {
        Anchor current = shape.getAnchor(i);
        path.lineTo(widthToScreenCoords(current.getX()), heightToScreenCoords(current.getY()));
    }

    path.close();

    mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

**EDIT:**

As stated in my comment: This happens when you use antialiasing on your paint. If anyone is interested: Use this snippet in a SurfaceView or normal View and you'll see:

[image]

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#12ffffff"));

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0f,0f);
    path.lineTo(300f, 0f);
    path.lineTo(300f, 100f);
    path.lineTo(0f, 300f);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Comment: `getColorInt()`, `getAnchor()`, `getAncorCount()` are not methods of the standard android `Shape` class. The `Anchor` class also does not appear to be part of the standard SDK. If they are third party, which library? If they are your own, please post code.

Comment: It's my own code, but i don't think it's relevant. The Color is saved as a "#aarrggbb" string and getColorInt() returns the Color.parse(String) int value. An anchor is just a 2D point and the anchor count is the number of 2D points that the shape consists of. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, it's hard to see anything obvious that is wrong with your code. Could you edit your question to list the set of shapes and their anchor point coordinates under your screen shots, to help trouble shoot this?

Comment: While I was removing every single bit of unnecessary information to offer you the most basic setup where this "bug" occures I found the solution. When I remove paint.setAntiAlias(true) everything works fine except I don't have antialiasing... For everyone who is interested and wants to play around and maybe find out why this happens, I add a code snipped to my OP. Thank you so far!